# My wordpress enqueue scripts are loading sometimes and other times are not

Tags: php, wordpress

really hoping for a bit of help..

I have a few scripts loading in the footer of a wordpress site.
The problem is sometimes they load fine and then other times they are not in the dom at all!

Anyone know of any reason for this inconsistency??

The site has been live for a few weeks and was fine, I've only today been made aware of this issue.

My code is below - anyone see any issues with it?

Also.. here is screenshot showing the missing content - top image is what it should be - bottom image shows missing scripts 
http://www.eskmills.com/wp-content/themes/eskmills/img/eskshot1.png

Big thanks in advance anyone!

ps. Ive spoke to the hosting company who are investigating but I'm expecting they will just tell me its for the developer to fix.

```
function eskmills_load_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'blazyjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/blazy.min.js', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'magnificjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magnific.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'eskmills_load_scripts');
```

Comment: Maybe there is some other code/plugin that unregisters `jquery`? Cache may be the cause too.

Comment: Site is only running 3 plugins; Advanced Custom Fields PRO, Custom Post Type UI and Yoast SEO. Each one is up to date.

Comment: Also running wordpress 4.8.2

Comment: Its really confusing as it doesn't happen all the time - and then when it does happen, if I refresh it often displays correctly

Comment: Have you tried running this website  in another server?

Comment: Yes, I have it also running on my own personal server on Media Temple - and its fine. I think I may have found the problem though. There is twitter feed php (Twitter Oauth) code in a div in the footer.php file. I removed it and the footer scripts seemed to have came back. Any idea why that may be happening?

Comment: Can't be sure, maybe the code is conflicting with the rest of footer's elements.

Comment: yes gutted about it - it was twitter api using TwitterOAuth to display a tweet. Any experience with it yourself?

Comment: Not at all, sorry.